# Best practices for embedding SVN version number in Java jar manifest?

Tags: svn, jar, manifest, manifest.mf

I see questions like [How to get revision number from subversion using maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654572/how-to-get-revision-number-from-subversion-using-maven) but are there any standards (defacto or otherwise) for which actual fields to use in the manifest, for the version # and for the repository URL (i.e., showing that it's on the trunk vs. a branch)?  I've seen Implementation-Version used, with and without a leading "r" (for revision), I've seen Implementation-Build: used as well.

**edit** I removed the maven tag, that shouldn't have been there. My question is about the jar contents, not the tooling per se.

Comment: No standards that I'm aware with. Every company/developer seems to have an opinion on how to manage revision numbers, never mind how to record and describe that revision :-)

Comment: You might want to consider using a file other than (or at least in addition to) the manifest if you ever want to read the revision number programatically.  Reading MANIFEST.MF from inside the JVM is actually quite a pain and can be inconsistent from one environment to another if the classloader hierarchy changes at all.

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670602/conventions-for-additional-content-of-the-manifest-mf-file

Comment: ha, glad this is a Popular Question. Now I just need to get around to doing this m'self.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, jar manifests by itself do not have any standard for version numbering.

But, actually, there is another standard way of getting revision number updated automatically. You could use [svn:keywords](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html) in order to get current revision number in your files after each commit. There is `$Revision$` property for revision substitution and `$HeadURL$` for repository URL substitution. You just need to put following string into the file and place this file under version control:

```
$Revision$ $HeadURL$
```

If you create manifest on the fly with maven, I would recommend putting following content into `version.properties` file:

```
revision=$Revision$
repourl=$HeadURL$
```

Then include in into `pom.xml` with the statement (maven should have properties plugin enabled):

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-alpha-1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>initialize</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <files>
            <file>version.properties</file>
          </files>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

And then you will be able to put revision number and repo url to the manifest:

```
<manifest>
  <attribute name="Revision" value="${revision}" />
  <attribute name="Repository URL" value="${repourl}" />
</manifest>
```

Please also note that you will need to [explicitly enable `svn:keywords`](http://www.ryannitz.org/tech-notes/2008/06/15/enable-svn-keyword-properties/) using subversion properties in order to get `$Revision$` and `$HeadURL$` substituted in your file with actual values. If you will decide to use `version.properties`, you will need to run following command:

```
svn propset svn:keywords Revision version.properties
svn propset svn:keywords HeadURL version.properties
```

Comment: thanks, one correction is that should be "Revision\ HeadURL" instead of "Id" in the propset.  However, that $Revision only includes the version of version.properties ( see: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html "where's globalrev" )  However, the $HeadURL$ doesn't change often (unless you svn switch a subdirectory).  So I should consider using HeadURL and not ignore keywords completely. Thanks.